# assume-unchanged なファイル一覧を取得したい

Tags: git

[git statusで特定のディレクトリ以下のファイルの変更を無視したい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/31194/754)
で、 `git update-index` に `--assume-unchanged` というオプションがあり、それによってインデックス情報を書き換えて、ファイルの変更を無視するようにすることができると知りました。

一方で、この場合、無視されているファイルの一覧が何であるかを知りたくなりますが、それの方法がわからずにいます。これは、どうやったら取得できますでしょうか。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

インデックス情報が変化するので`git help ls-files`を見てみました。
-v オプションで確認できるようです。

```
-v
    Similar to -t, but use lowercase letters for files that are marked as assume unchanged (see git-update-index(1)).
```

但し`assume unchanged`でないインデックス情報(uppercase)も全て表示されるので、`assume unchanged`のファイルのみ(lowercase)を確認するのであれば、以下のようにする必要があります。

```
git ls-files -v  | grep ^h
```